# Can I post Python scraped articles to my wordpress site using XML-RPC?

Tags: python, php, wordpress, web-scraping

I am new to programming and learned a little bit of Python in the previous two weeks and wrote an automation script that scrapes Categories and articles in each category from a website. Now I want to test that script on my WordPress blog and post articles in their respective categories in the WordPress blog. Can someone direct me to any thorough guide to executing this process? I have done some research on this but there is very little information available on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to write a php code (in your site) where you will upload the json file. the script will then save data to your database .Modify the  python script to save the scraped data in json(many languages easily support it + has more usage and is faster) then upload it to the php file.From database you can display your data

Comment: I have literally no knowledge of PHP and I don't want to open two fronts at the same time. My prime focus is to learn Python and implement whatever I code. So I am only looking for suggestions/resources to run this script on WordPress the easiest way as I already have knowledge of WordPress.

Comment: it is not a must you learn it all. the script can take you 30 min tops. then that will solve your issue. but if it is a must you only use python you could migrate to Django web. quite easy

Comment: Can you please share some resources to achieve what you have explained in your answer? Which one is easiest? that PHP way or Django?

Comment: php way. go to  [this site ](http://mrbool.com/how-to-insert-retrieve-json-data-to-from-database-using-php/36810). shows how to go about it